# How do I convert a dynamic web application to a war

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a really simple and stupid question.

I have a dynamic web application in eclipse that I am trying to convert to a WAR file and haven't had much luck finding the answer on the net.

It is not a maven project, just a regular dynamic web application created from start.  Surprisingly this is proving to be an annoying little task

It is deployed with Tomcat.  I don't know if that makes any difference.

Thanks for everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 7):

Right click your project, select `Export` and `WAR file`. You can then configure what goes in and what doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am trying to upload the war file to a website and the site's server is using an older version of Tomcat.  Assuming that everything is configured correctly on the project, will it be able to run on an older Tomcat server?

Comment: @user1888771 You'll have to find out what Servlet API version the server runs and make sure your application is compatible. For example Servlet 3.0 is only supported on Tomcat 6+.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for your help.  One last stupid question, where do I find the servlet versions?\

Comment: @user1888771 For your application, check version the declaration at the top of your `web.xml`. However, you still need to be using `javax.servlet` classes that are compatible with that version. For your Tomcat installation, see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-check-tomcat-version-installed/).

Comment: @user1888771 You're welcome. Consider accepting the answer unless there's something missing.